# deploy node front end and python back end in heroku

Tags: python, node.js, django, heroku

I am a beginner to deploying apps, I have a NuxtJS front end and a Django back end that I want to deploy to Horku. I've looked at every tutorial and Stackoverflow post on how to achieve this, but everyone says to do the same thing which doesn't work.

things I have tried:

- adding a Python and node build pack with adding the nuxt build to Django static files (tutorial I followed: https://github.com/mdrhmn/react-dj-todoapp/blob/master/README.md)
- that didn't work so I made docker images which I got successfully running locally but couldn't deploy to Heroku with heroku.yml file
- finally, I made two separate apps on Heroku and deployed each app separately which works fine but I don't like this solution
- Procfile(for the first option to deploy both together):

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn backend.wsgi --log-file -
```

- I tried adding both `.ouput/server` and `output/public` to Django static files which I can see in the Heroku bash

note: if I change the `web` command to `npm start` the frontend would work but not the backend and vice versa

I know that Heroku uses dynos and only exposes one port for the app but I don't know how to use that information to make it work

does anyone have ideas on how to make this work?